# How can i bring google earth map from Arcgis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth, google-earth-pro

I would like to know in which way I can bring any Google earth or earth pro maps from ArcGiS? There are some solutions I already find. I need to know the easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

[Arc2Earth](http://www.arc2earth.com/)

> Arc2Earth was designed to provide a “bridge” between ArcGIS Desktop
>   and other GIS solutions—such as those from Google, MapBox and CartoDB,
>   as well as other Esri solutions. Arc2Earth is simple to install,
>   simple to use and simple to integrate with your existing GIS.

However there is pricing, but its a good integration between the two.

Also check the [Esri Basemaps](http://www.esri.com/data/basemaps), they maybe sufficient, pending your region and scale levels.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ArcGIS Online Server for loading a basemaps , you have to make a connection to it from inside your Catalog to access the key basemaps: In the Add ArcGIS Server connection dialog, paste this URL into the Server URL field: http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/services. You can then browse the services it contains.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use google maps in ArcGIS, you can download & install the GoogleMaps Download tool from GTO Software. We developed a free version for ArcGIS 10.1. You can get it from here: [GoogleMap Download](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pemXj8pS-8Y)